# Как полностью остановить объект при респавне?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Сфера после респавна продолжает двигаться в том же направлении в каком была до. Как можно сделать так, чтобы при респавне она останавливалась?

```
public Rigidbody rb;
public float force;
public Transform respawn;
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        rb.AddForce(Vector3.forward * force * Time.deltaTime);
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        rb.AddForce(Vector3.forward * -force * Time.deltaTime);
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        rb.AddForce(Vector3.right * force * Time.deltaTime);
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        rb.AddForce(Vector3.right * -force * Time.deltaTime);

    if (transform.position.y < 1.82064) // Если упал, то респавн
    {
        transform.position = respawn.transform.position + new Vector3(0, 0.6F, 0);
    }
}
```

Is kinematic если что пробовал, как можно по другому?

Answer (score 1):

Обнулите свойство `velocity` у компонента `rb` после респавна. И не нужно использовать `AddForce` для перемещения объекта, просто присваивайте `Rigidbody` нужное ускорение (`velocity`). Так намного проще, потому что не нужно думать что такое force и какую величину нужно задать, чтобы объект двигался с нужной скоростью.

Comment: Когда обнуляю velocity `rb.velocity = new Vector3(0,0,0) * 0;` то сфера при респавне уже не так быстро, но продолжает катиться. Попробовал другое управление, но в нём сфера катится с фиксированной скоростью, а мне требуется чтобы она разгонялась

Comment: Чтобы она ускорялась, вы можете прибавлять ускорение, пока оно не достигнет максимального значения, а не просто устанавливать максимум. И для обнуления достаточно присвоить ускорению `Vector3.zero` и не использовать конструкции, типа вашей `new Vector3(0,0,0) * 0`

Comment: @KOTIK `не нужно использовать AddForce` -- это утверждение в общем случае ошибочно. Velocity устанавливает определенный вектор скорости и придерживается его, в то время как AddForce берет в расчет другие параметры, например, трение. `не нужно думать что такое force` - есть всего 4 варианта, из которых не сложно выбрать: учитывать ли вес или нет, постоянная ли это сила (как когда толкаем ящик) или мгновенная (как когда бьем по шару в бильярде).

Comment: @МаксимФисман `это утверждение в общем случае ошибочно` это утверждение может быть ошибочно только в играх, где на физике построены основные механики. Для управления чем-либо, в данном случае сферой, `AddForce` является максимально глупым решением. Что удобнее для геймдизайна: придать скорость 5м/с или силу 5000дж? `есть всего 4 варианта...`  опять же, что удобнее: задать постоянную скорость 5м\с или силу в 3987дж? Задать начальную скорость шара в 5м/с или силу в 8765дж? И проблема не только в геймдизайне, гораздо проще и удобнее делать вычисления, основываясь на скорости, нежели на силе.

Comment: `это утверждение может быть ошибочно` - это и называется общий случай. Если уж вы так рьяно отметаете AddForce, то стоит отметить "область определения", например: "**в вашем случае** не стоит использовать AddForce", "**для подобного поведения**...", "**здесь**..." и т.п., иначе возникает ощущение, что вы считаете, что AddForce вообще вреден и создан зря, а это не так. В данном случае (!), конечно, легче устанавливать скорость velocity, но это не всегда так. Кстати, с чего вы взяли. что у ТС основные механики не построены на физике? Может у него есть то же трение:)

Comment: @МаксимФисман `стоит отметить "область определения"` Прямая цитата из моего ответа - `И не нужно использовать AddForce для перемещения объекта`. `AddForce вообще вреден и создан зря` так, как его используют в большинстве обучающих материалов, он вреден. `Кстати, с чего вы взяли. что у ТС основные механики не построены на физике?` да с того, что я вижу код и могу понять, что это человек, который только начал изучать движок и вряд ли у него сейчас цель сделать игру с реалистичной системой физики. `трение` скажу по секрету, но трение можно симулировать из кода.

Comment: "Для перемещения обьекта" - это не область определения) Ну спорить особо бессмысленно, т.к. ТС как-то не особо проявляет интерес к своему собственному вопросу :)